# SQL: take first match, or second if first is null, or both if both are present (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, conditional-statements

> table1.created_at BETWEEN '2014-10-02 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2014-10-02
>   23:59:59 UTC' AND table2.created_at BETWEEN '2014-10-02 00:00:00 UTC'
>   AND '2014-10-02 23:59:59 UTC'

I have some joins and another queries as well, but this is that interesting for me.

So, if I have some records in a range of first table - I should take it.
If in first and second - values from both one.
If in second only - from second.

Now if one of tables is empty - I have empty result.
If I will use OR - I will have records only from one of tables, as well.

How should I rewrite query to have expected result?

Comment: PostgreSQL. Updated in tags, thx

Comment: Change the logic that connects the conditions from  `and` to `or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you break your query up into two separate queries, one testing against the `table1` date, the other against the `table2` date.  Then you can use `UNION ALL` to combine them, which should yield the behavior you are asking for.

Sample:

```
SELECT t1.Data1, ...
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON ...
WHERE t1.Created_at BETWEEN '2014-10-02 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2014-10-02 23:59:59 UTC'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.Data1, ...
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON ...
WHERE t2.Created_at BETWEEN '2014-10-02 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2014-10-02 23:59:59 UTC'
```

EDIT

Based on your example, I'd do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all,
    users.id AS users_id 
FROM 
(
    SELECT users.id
    FROM "users" 
        LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.col1_id = cols1.id 
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.col2_id = cols2.id 
    WHERE "users"."role_id" IN (1,2,4,5,6,7,8)
        AND table1.created_at BETWEEN '2014-09-27 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2014-10-03 23:59:59 UTC' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT users.id
    FROM "users" 
        LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.col1_id = cols1.id 
        LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.col2_id = cols2.id 
    WHERE "users"."role_id" IN (1,2,4,5,6,7,8)
        AND table2.created_at BETWEEN '2014-09-27 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2014-10-03 23:59:59 UTC' 
)
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: I've added pastie with my example, apply your UNION ALL example according to it, please:
http://pastie.org/private/gnexgxuqih2tzxn0ja2a

Comment: Based on what it appears you want, this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE table1.created_at BETWEEN '2014-10-02 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2014-10-02 23:59:59 UTC' 

UNION ALL

SELECT *
  FROM table2
 WHERE table2.created_at BETWEEN '2014-10-02 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2014-10-02 23:59:59 UTC'
```

Make sure table1 has the same number of columns as table2 does.

Comment: I've added pastie with my example, apply your UNION ALL example according to it, please:
http://pastie.org/private/gnexgxuqih2tzxn0ja2a

Comment: What are cols1 and cols2, there are not such aliases?

Comment: it's just another columns in tables

Comment: What table holds these columns?

Comment: table1 and table2 accordingly, as LEFT JOIN says

Comment: So are you trying to join tables using only column of one tables? I guess it will be better if show me the structures of your tables.